# Integral of $\cosh^3(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration

What is the integral of $\cosh^3(x)$? And how exactly can I calculate it? I've tried setting $\cosh^3(x)=(\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2})^3$ but all I get in the end is one long fraction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** $\cosh^3x=\cosh x\cdot\cosh^2x=\sinh'x\cdot\big(1+\sinh^2x\big)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint this is better to integrate $$\frac{e^{-3 x}}{8}+\frac{3 e^{-x}}{8}+\frac{3 e^x}{8}+\frac{e^{3 x}}{8}$$
integrating this we get $$-\frac{e^{-3x}}{24}-\frac{3}{8}e^{-x}+\frac{3}{8}e^{x}+\frac{e^{3x}}{24}+C$$

Comment: That's how far I've come, too. But I can't seem to get past this step.

Comment: What more do you expect to do?  You have the answer.  Are you trying to convert it to an expression in sinh and cosh?

Comment: Yes, I don't understand how WolframAlpha got $\frac{1}{12}(9\sinh(x)+\sinh(3x))+c$

Comment: this is the same as $$-\frac{1}{24} e^{-3 x}-\frac{3 e^{-x}}{8}+\frac{3 e^x}{8}+\frac{e^{3 x}}{24}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int \cosh^3(x)dx=\int (\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2})^3dx=\frac{1}{8}\int (e^{3x}+3e^{x}+3e^{-x}+e^{-3x})dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{8} (\frac{1}{3}e^{3x}+3e^{x}-3e^{-x}-\frac{1}{3}e^{-3x})+C$$
$$=\frac{2}{24}\sinh(3x)+\frac{3}{4}\sinh(x)+C$$

Comment: Can this be simplified some more?

Answer (score -1):

\begin{align}
\int\cosh^3x dx & = \int\left(\sinh^2x +1\right)\cosh x dx \\
& = \frac{1}{3}\int3\sinh^2x\cosh x dx +\int \cosh x dx \\
& = \frac{1}{3}\sinh^3 x + \sinh x + C\\
\end{align}